# check string equal with regex

Tags: c++

I have a simple question.

How would i check if my string equals another string if that string has changing numbers at the end.

```
Random:1
Random (1):1
Random (2):1
Random (3):1
Random (4):1
So on...
```

and also with a string like this

```
Random
Random_1
Random_2
Random_3
Random_4
So on...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need `std::regex_match` and `std::regex` from `<regex>`:

```
#include <regex>

bool match(const char* cstr)
{
    static auto re = std::regex("Random \\([0-9]*\\):1"); // or whatever regex you'd like
    return std::regex_match(cstr, re);
}
```

Comment: @jotehas373 fixed regex & tested this time, it should work now.

Comment: any idea why this would crash on this line std::regex_match(paraName, std::regex("Random_\\[0-9]*"))

Comment: @jotehas373 you likely wanted to write double backslash in the string. That's because it's a c string where single backslash is an escape character.